# Cannot connect server and client using named pipes

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I read a lot of examples on the interenet of named pipes. For some reason I cannot make it work. Anyways here is my code:

**Server:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("1234");
        server.WaitForConnection();

        Console.Beep(); // connection successful! 
    }
```

**Client:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                    
        NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream("1234");
        client.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

I have two different executables. I start the server program first then the client. Why I am not able to connect?

Comment: Your code works for me, although I did replace Console.Beep with `Console.WriteLine("Connected!");` and `Console.Read();`

Comment: This code works for me too so what is not working Tono Nam

Comment: Maybe `Console.Beep` is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason: you are launching processes from 2 different security contexts (i.e. one "run as administrator" and another as regular user). In this case connection can't be established without setting security on the named pipe...

There may also be existing named pipe with this name (orphaned in some way or under another user), but I'd expect at least one of the program to fail in this case. Consider restarting your machine just in case (or better use one of the Sysitnerals tools to see if there is already pipe with this name).